# Select columns based on characters in their headers and calculate % difference

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset derived from joining two separate datasets together. Both have yearly counts that I want to calculate the percentage difference between without having to write lines for every year to make it more efficient for datasets spanning many more years than this example.

Here is what I have:

```
link_col <- c("A0001", "A0002", "A0003")
ABC_2019 <- c(1000, 300, 5000)
ABC_2020 <- c(800, 600, 2000)
ABC_2021 <- c(600, 100, 900)
ABC_DEF_2019_GHI <- c(1100, 400, 4800)
ABC_DEF_2020_GHI <- c(900, 600, 2100)
ABC_DEF_2021_GHI <- c(500, 200, 800)
data <- data.frame(link_col, ABC_2019, ABC_2020, ABC_2021, 
                   ABC_DEF_2019_GHI, ABC_DEF_2020_GHI, ABC_DEF_2021_GHI)
data

  link_col ABC_2019 ABC_2020 ABC_2021 ABC_DEF_2019_GHI ABC_DEF_2020_GHI ABC_DEF_2021_GHI
1    A0001     1000      800      600             1100              900              500
2    A0002      300      600      100              400              600              200
3    A0003     5000     2000      900             4800             2100              800
```

What I'm most interested in learning are commands, possibly from `dplyr`, that identify the same year within the different columns (e.g. 2019 within ABC_2019 and ABC_DEF_2019_GHI) and can then apply these columns to different processes like dividing or subtracting them. In this case, I'd like to apply these matching columns to this % difference equation and create new columns containing the result for each year:

```
diff_2019 <- ((ABC_DEF_2019_GHI - ABC_2019)/ABC_2019)*100
diff_2020 <- ((ABC_DEF_2020_GHI - ABC_2020)/ABC_2020)*100
diff_2021 <- ((ABC_DEF_2021_GHI - ABC_2021)/ABC_2021)*100
```

Here is the dataset I'm after in this instance, but some explanation on how to select columns by heading characters this would be greatly appreciated!

```
data2 <- data.frame(link_col, ABC_2019, ABC_2020, ABC_2021, 
                    ABC_DEF_2019_GHI, ABC_DEF_2020_GHI, ABC_DEF_2021_GHI, 
                    diff_2019, diff_2020, diff_2021)
data2

  link_col ABC_2019 ABC_2020 ABC_2021 ABC_DEF_2019_GHI ABC_DEF_2020_GHI ABC_DEF_2021_GHI diff_2019 diff_2020 diff_2021
1    A0001     1000      800      600             1100              900              500  10.00000      12.5 -16.66667
2    A0002      300      600      100              400              600              200  33.33333       0.0 100.00000
3    A0003     5000     2000      900             4800             2100              800  -4.00000       5.0 -11.11111
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Select the group of columns with `grep`
2. Create a year vector
3. Compute the share

```r
cols1 <- grep("ABC_\\d+", colnames(data), value = TRUE)
cols2 <- grep("ABC_DEF_.*", colnames(data), value = TRUE)
years <- gsub("ABC_", "", cols1)
data[paste0("diff", years)] <- (data[cols2] - data[cols1]) / data[cols1] * 100

#   link_col ABC_2019 ABC_2020 ABC_2021 ABC_DEF_2019_GHI ABC_DEF_2020_GHI ABC_DEF_2021_GHI diff2019 diff2020  diff2021
# 1    A0001     1000      800      600             1100              900              500 10.00000     12.5 -16.66667
# 2    A0002      300      600      100              400              600              200 33.33333      0.0 100.00000
# 3    A0003     5000     2000      900             4800             2100              800 -4.00000      5.0 -11.11111
```